# Is repartition necessary for data join when I do cache in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have a table join operation like the following

```
rData = [rd1, rd2, rd3, ...] # a list of spark dataframe

# option 1: lData.cache()
# option 2: lData = lData.repartition('joinKey').cache()

result = None
for rd in rData:
    tmp = lData.join(rd, on='joinKey') # lData is a spark dataframe
    result = tmp if not result else result.unionByName(tmp)
```

As you can see, `lData` is repeatedly used in data joins against `rData` elements. I'm thinking of cache `lData` in memory in order to get good performance on data join (`option 1` in above code). In this case, should I also consider repartition of `lData` by `joinKey` so that the shuffle on lData can be avoided in the process of join against `rData` (`option2` in above code), or is it necessary? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Repartition does a full shuffle, creates new partitions, and increases the level of parallelism in the application. More partitions will help to deal with the data skewness problem with an extra cost that is a shuffling of full data as mentioned above. However adding one shuffle to the query plan might eliminate two other shuffles, and speed up the running. So I think if your data is skewed then only you should go with repartitioning.

Answer (score 0):

When you are joining 2 dataframes, repartition is not going to help, it will be sparks shuffle service which will decide the number of shuffles.
For E.G. :-
you do this

```
lData.repartition(100).join(rData)
```

and consider your default shuffle partition as 200, you will see that while joining you will have 200 tasks, which is equal to sparks shuffle partition.

Moreover the approach is very inefficient.

You can use below directly, you don't need to loop over rdata

```
lData.join(rData, on='joinKey')
```